# Am I implementing this algorithm correctly in Lua 5.3?

Tags: algorithm, math, lua, bit-manipulation

```
-- (1451AFBx - 1A7D575) ^ (-1C6B438x + i)
-- y = ( Ax + B )^( Cx + D )
-- x0 = B0 ^ D0 ^ y0

math.randomseed( os.time( ) );

local UINT32_MAX = 2^32 - 1;

local A = 0x1451AFB
local B = -0x1A7D575;
local C = -0x1C6B438;
local D =  math.random( 0, UINT32_MAX );
local x = math.random( 0, UINT32_MAX );
local y = bit32.bxor( A * x + B, C * x + D );

x = { };

local function printf( msg, ... )
    print( string.format( msg, ... ) );
end

local function getBit( n, i )
    return ( ( n & ( 1 << ( i - 1 ) ) ) > 0 ) and 1 or 0;
end

for i = 1, 32 do
    table.insert( x, 1, math.floor( bit32.bxor( getBit( B, i ), getBit( D, i ), getBit( y, i ) ) ) );
end

x = tonumber( table.concat( x ), 2 );
local y2 = bit32.bxor( A * x + B, C * x + D );

assert( y ==  y2,  string.format( 'Invalid solution: %u ~= %u', y, y2 ) );
printf( 'x = %u', x );
```

Output from [this](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) Lua interpreter:

```
input:33: Invalid solution: 3996422455 ~= 2979830783
```

The above algorithm is based on the answer I received [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884500/how-to-solve-this-equation-for-x-with-xor-involved) on the mathematics StackExchange. Before I award the answer the bounty, I want to make sure that the algorithm he described actually works. However, it seems that my assertion always fails. Is it his algorithm that is wrong or my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized a made a stupid mistake.

This algorithm:

```
for i = 1, 32 do
    table.insert( x, 1, math.floor( bit32.bxor( getBit( B, i ), getBit( D, i ), getBit( y, i ) ) ) );
end
```

Essentially did this obfuscated:

```
x = bit32.xor( B, D, y );
```

Yet that is obviously not what he intended.

The actual code that should be place of the above for-loop snippet is the following:

```
local b = B;
local d = D;

for i = 1, 32 do
    table.insert( x, 1, math.floor( bit32.bxor( getBit( b, 1 ), getBit( d, 1 ), getBit( y, i ) ) ) );
    b = ( A * x[1] + b ) // 2;
    d = ( C * x[1] + d ) // 2;
end
```

The code now passes the assertion.